DAPR - Regarding custom middleware to setup in the pipeline and how to create and register it
Please let me know how to create the dapr custom middleware in c#
how to register it.
And how to configure it in a microservice to use it.
Please let me know in detailed steps as I have been struggling a lot on this.
Please pass the sample application from top to bottom steps with yaml configuration file and component.
Not even sure how to register it and how can i use it in other microservice.
Created the middle ware like this
public class DaprCustomAuthMiddleware : IMiddleware
{
    public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context, RequestDelegate next)
    {
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
        Console.WriteLine($"******************Incoming request: {context.Request.Path}**********************************");

        // Call the next middleware in the pipeline
        await next(context);

        // Log outgoing response
        Console.WriteLine($"\"******************Outgoing response: {context.Response.StatusCode}\"******************");
    }
}

On startup did like this
public class Startup
{
  
    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Configures Services.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="services">Service Collection.</param>
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        //services.AddDaprClient();
        services.AddTransient<DaprCustomAuthMiddleware>();
        services.AddSingleton(new JsonSerializerOptions()
        {
            PropertyNamingPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase,
            PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true,
        });
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Configures Application Builder and WebHost environment.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="app">Application builder.</param>
    /// <param name="env">Webhost environment.</param>
    /// <param name="serializerOptions">Options for JSON serialization.</param>
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, JsonSerializerOptions serializerOptions,
        ILogger<Startup> logger)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseMiddleware<DaprCustomAuthMiddleware>();
        app.UseCloudEvents();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
          //  endpoints.MapSubscribeHandler();
            endpoints.MapGet("dapr/subscribe", async context =>
            {
                // Handle subscription request
                // For example: return the subscription response
                await context.Response.WriteAsync("{\"topics\": [\"topic1\", \"topic2\"]}");
            });

            endpoints.MapGet("dapr/config", async context =>
            {
                // Handle subscription request
                // For example: return the subscription response
                await context.Response.WriteAsync("Config reached successfully");
            });

            endpoints.MapGet("/", async context =>
            {
                // Handle subscription request
                // For example: return the subscription response
                await context.Response.WriteAsync("Get reached successfully");
            });
        });

    }
}

Now I want to use this middleware registered in dapr so that I could use it across the microservices communication.
I tried something
apiVersion: dapr.io/v1alpha1
kind: Component
metadata:
  name: DaprConsoleApp
spec:
  type: middleware.http
  version: v1
  metadata:
    - name: not sure what to enter 
      value: not sure what to enter code here`


So I need help from end to end steps

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Below are the steps to accomplish this, including the C# code for the middleware, the ASP.NET Core startup configuration, and the Dapr YAML configuration for the middleware component.

Used this git Microservices with Dapr in DotNet.

Define Custom Middleware:

public class DaprCustomAuthMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    public DaprCustomAuthMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context)
    {
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
        Console.WriteLine($"******************Incoming request: {context.Request.Path}**********************************");

        // Call the next middleware in the pipeline
        await _next(context);

        // Log outgoing response
        Console.WriteLine($"******************Outgoing response: {context.Response.StatusCode}******************");
    }






Custom Middleware in Startup:

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    // Other middleware registrations...

    app.UseMiddleware<DaprCustomAuthMiddleware>();

    // Other middleware registrations...
}





I Followed this link to Configure middleware components  in  Dapr

Dapr Middleware Configuration:
apiVersion: dapr.io/v1alpha1
kind: Configuration
metadata:
  name: dapr-custom-auth-middleware
spec:
  httpPipeline:
    handlers:
      - name: custom-auth
        type: middleware.http.custom

(or)
apiVersion: dapr.io/v1alpha1
kind: Component
metadata:
  name: dapr-custom-auth-middleware
spec:
  type: middleware.http
  version: v1
  metadata:
    - name: handlerType
      value: middleware





Output:


For Azure samples middleware-oauth-microsoft, follow this git.


how our c# code middleware gets linked to the component yaml...
value :middleware is the one that attaches it and you have run the middleware as a microservice with app-id as "middleware". please confirm this

i tried running the middleware as service using app-id "middleware" but the error comes middleware not registered

i ran the middleware like this
dapr run --app-id DaprConsoleApp --app-port 5000  dotnet run
then I made the component yaml like
apiVersion: dapr.io/v1alpha1
kind: Component
metadata:
name: DaprCustomAuthMiddleware
spec:
type: middleware.http
version: v1
metadata:
- name: handlerType
value: DaprConsoleApp
but still, it's giving me middleware not registered.

I have followed this for example for confirmation of middle ware

This example is simply showing middleware or some logic to implement. How to register the middleware and use it for another services its not showing.

Can u share the updated registration process steps with proper yaml and steps mentioning the linking of middleware and its usage

Any updates on this Sampath. Please let me know

The versions on the component have to match. v1alpha1 vs v1 may be the problem here
